# R package RcppEigen installation failed

Tags: c++, r, ubuntu, rcpp

I am trying to install `hts` package for R in Ubuntu Server. The RcppEigen package which is a dependency for the hts package keeps failing to install.
I tried installing from the source and from the devtools. The same error persist.

F.Y.I : The ubuntu server is inside a virtual machine and I am trying to configure shiny server in it.

`install.packages('RcppEigen')` dependency for `hts` package installation failed Ubuntu Linux.

```
g++ internal compiler error: killed (program cc1plus)
```

Comment: Check your VM settings: do you have very little RAM?  That's what googling this error message suggests.

Comment: @BenBolker is correct, and someone _please_ find one of the several duplicates.  You are simply out of RAM for the (somewhat complex) C++ you are trying to compile.

Comment: Also: `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rcppeigen` gets you a pre-built binary. See http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=r-cran-rcppeigen

Comment: Thank you very much!, I got a pre-compiled library and got it sorted for now. I think RAM was the issue.